# Consulta em tabela de relacionamento N:N

Tags: mysql, sql

Como exibir todos os projetos que possuem um orientador específico?

A relação entre Orientador e Projeto é de `N:N`, por isso, contém a tabela `Projeto_has_Orientador` como tabela do relacionamento.

Tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Orientador (
  idOrientador INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  Email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  CPF VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (idOrientador))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Projeto (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Projeto_has_Orientador (
  Projeto_id INT NOT NULL,
  Orientador_idOrientador INT NOT NULL,
  TipoOrientador INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Projeto_id, Orientador_idOrientador),
FOREIGN KEY (Projeto_id)
REFERENCES Projeto (id)
FOREIGN KEY (Orientador_idOrientador)
REFERENCES Orientador (idOrientador)
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT projeto.id as id, orientador.Nome as orientador, 
FROM  projeto
INNER JOIN orientador ON (orientador.idOrientador = (select P.Orientador_idOrientador from projeto_has_orientador as P where P.Projeto_id = projeto.id AND P.Tipo_Orientador = 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente desta maneira:

```
SELECT O.NOME, P.TITULO, FROM Orientador AS O
INNER JOIN Projeto_has_Orientador AS P ON (P.idOrientador = O.idOrientador)
WHERE P.idOrientador = <id do orientador>
```

[Aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/inner-cross-left-rigth-e-full-joins/21016) vc pode consequir mais informações de consulta usando o `JOIN`.